# Fourth Proof of the infinitude of primes in "Proofs from THE BOOK"

Tags: number-theory

I was gifted *Proofs from THE BOOK* and recently started flipping through some of the proofs.The fourth proof of the infinitude of primes (Euler's proof) has raised some questions on my end.

#### First Question

The proof starts by stating that for $n \leq x \leq n+1$,

$$ \log(x) \leq 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n-1} + \dfrac{1}{n} $$

And then claims

$$ \log(x) \leq \sum \dfrac{1}{m} $$

quote "where the sum extends over all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ which have only prime divisors $p\leq x$".  Why is this true?  Since 1 is not prime, isn't $\sum 1/m$ actually less than the partial sum of the harmonic series?

The proof continues...

#### Second Question

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, every such $m$ can be written as

$$ m = \prod_{p \leq x} p^{k_p} $$

and so

$$ \sum \dfrac{1}{m} = \prod_{\underset{p \leq x}{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \left( \sum_{0 \leq k} \dfrac{1}{p^k} \right) $$

Where $\mathbb{P}$ are the set of primes.  Are the product and sums commutable like that, or have I just missed some key property of primes?

Answer (score 2):

First question: 1 has no prime factors, and so all of its prime factors are less than $x$ -- You can't name any counterexample, can you?

Second question: It's unrelated to commutativity. That's just plain distributivity: $a(b+c)=ab+ac$, dressed up in all those sigma's and pi's. Write a few intermediate steps and you should be able to see that.

Comment: That's a good point about 1.